# which of the two estimators is better?

Tags: probability

Given a random size 3 sample of a population with mean $μ$ and variance $s^2$, it was choose two estimators from $μ$:

$\bar{\theta_1}=\bar{x}$ and $\bar{\theta_2}=\frac{x_1+3x_2+x_3}{5}$

in terms of risk. which of the two estimators is better?

**My attempt:**

We know

$E[\bar{x}]=E[\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{n}]=\mu$

$E[\frac{X_1+3X_2+X_3}{5}]=\frac{1}{5}E[X_1]+3E[X_2]+E[X_3]=\mu$

So our two estimators are both unbiased estimators of $μ.$

Moreover,

$V[\bar{x}]=V[\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{n}]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$

$V[\frac{X_1+3X_2+X_3}{5}]=\frac{1}{25}[\sigma^2+9\sigma^2+\sigma^2]=\frac{11\sigma^2}{25}$

Here my doubt. depend of valor of $n$ the answer to this question. no?

Comment: I thought $n=3$.

Comment: oh, true true thanks :D @BenW